# Right-Side of InputText

Tags: visualforce

I want to show label or some text right-side of apex:inputtext.

1. I created VisualForce Page.
2. I use inputText in this page.
3. I want to show text Right-Side of inputText.
4. But, this text is disturbed by the style of salesforce.

What Should I do?

```
    <apex:page  showHeader="true" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" id="page" tabStyle="Account" standardStylesheets="true" lightningStylesheets="false">

    <apex:form  >
        <div id="all">
            <div id="form">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:pageBlock title="title">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection id="inputForm">
                            <apex:inputText label="Label" maxlength="2" >Text1</apex:inputText>
                            <apex:inputText label="Label" maxlength="2" />Text1
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>

        </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

↑this image,
I want to do Lower Textbox & 「text1」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none">
    ...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

to make multiple tags appear like one tag and `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` allows a field and label to be put together manually. So try something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="title">
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        ...
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Label" for="input0"/>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                <apex:inputText id="input0"/>
                Text1
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: This code is what I want to do ! Thank you so much :)